# ¿Cómo tener varios proyectos en un solo repositorio de Git?

Tags: html, css, git, github, git-push

estoy estudiando programación, ya he hecho varios proyectos que me han dejado, pero tengo una pregunta, es posible que tenga todos mis proyectos en un solo repositorio?
Gracias

Comment: es posible, pero complicado de seguir los cambios y al clonar te trae todo, fijate [submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules)

Comment: muchas gracias, mejor lo hago por separado

Comment: Proyectos separados? Podrías tener un repositorio diganos `tareas` por decir algo, y luego tener ramas independientes (`tarea1`,  `tarea2`,  etc) arrancando ramas _huérfanas_ (usando `git checkout --orphan`) de tal forma que no hay relación entre las ramas.

Comment: clarooo, no habia caido en cuenta, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Por supuesto que puedes, lo ideal en ese caso sería que guardes cada uno en un folder y así puedas gestionar cada uno de la manera que se te acomode mejor.

Aquí te puedo mostrar un repositorio que tengo, "api" es un proyecto en Laravel y "reactfront" otro proyecto con React. Ambos son indispensables para funcionar  del modo que se quiere, en tu caso deberías medir además la magnitud de los proyectos que tienes, si son complejos o suficientemente sencillos lo cual ya está en tu decisión ver cómo manejarlos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Siii, eso eraxactamente lo que queria, pense que no se podía, me puse a investigar y mover todas las carpetas, y logré hacerlo, muchas gracias:)